# retrieving files with google drive sdk rest

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-drive-api

I'm developing a simple app which list all files founds in google drive.

So far, so good. the problem is that list retrieved contains all version of files.

If, for example, There's a file with 3 different versions, all file version will be retrieved, so 3 file with same names
So my question is:
Using javascript rest api how can retrieve only current version of files?

this is how I retrieve file list:

```
make_request("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files")
.then((files)=>{
    console.log(print_files(files));
});
```

make_request and print_files are custom functions.

Comment: In the future you should supply enough code for someone to test it.  We cant test your custom functions.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) Lists or searches files.

Returns a list of all of the files on your Google Drive account.  If you have more then one file with the same name drive will still return it.   There is no way to sort files or group by files and only return one of them.

You will need to download the full list and sort though it locally.